# How to escape quotes in a MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Example: The follwing query give me Quotes error in the field -> GET['email']

```
    mysql_query(" select * from user_info where user_mail = '$_GET['email']' ")
```

Comment: No matter which way you go, please consider the SQL injection issues!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to escape the string first:

```
$_GET['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
```

And then:

```
mysql_query(" select * from user_info where user_mail = '" . $_GET['email'] . "' ");
```

The dots put the strings together.

Answer (score 1):

Use accolades like this.

```
mysql_query(" select * from user_info where user_mail = '{$_GET['email']}' ")
```

Also, make sure to escape your user input. Your current setup looks like it is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to clean up your user input (like $_GET values)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an answer to your question, but I'd strongly advise you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/book.mysqli.php) prepared statements. Thus, your original problem -- the escaping parameter strings -- will be automatically taken care of.

If you do not want to follow this advice, do this:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
mysql_query("select * from user_info where user_mail = '$email';");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotation marks for associative array field names if you are already inside a doubly-quoted string:

```
$str = "Hello $_GET[email].";
```

Comment: You can also always concat the values: `$str = "Hello ".$_GET['email'];` which helps legibility IMHO.

Comment: Many solutions...  you an also wrap the variable in braces: `"Hello {$_GET['email']}"`, or `"Hello {$_GET["email"]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_mail = '".$_GET['email']."'";
mysql_query($SQL);
```

But I strongly advice to take some security actions with `$_GET['email']`, like this:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_mail = '".$email."'";
mysql_query($SQL);
```